# When can I use "to" instead of "of"?

Tags: grammar, meaning, word-usage, prepositions

I have been noticing that sometimes when referring to ownership, the preposition *to* is frequently more accurate than *of.* For example, consider the phrase 
*"These are the keys **to** the door,"* and *"These are the keys **of** the door."* Is there any pattern to clearly differentiate when to use one over the other?

Or, for example, "I am new **to** this store." In this case, can I use another preposition other than **to**?

Answer (score 2):

What you are considering here are established expressions, such as **new to...** and **keys to....**

Whether you use these prepositions or others depends on the context. While these can be the **keys to the door**, they can also be the **keys of the kingdom** or **the keys in the drawer**.

And while you can be **new to the store**, you can also be **new in this department**, **new around the block**, **new under our roof**, **new for the purposes of...** and so on.

The context is everything.